# Printer Artwork editing library or plugin for web based application

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Am a web developer of few years of experience in HTML/PHP. Please, can someone hint me on how to do something like the one on the following links:

http://www.vistaprint.com/studio.aspx?template=2920140_B73_023&ag=True&xnav=HSG_Design_Image&rd=1

I will really appreciate any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the ability to drag/edit elements. It looks like they are jquery ui library to do this. Here's a demo of the draggable feature: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

This is of course just the dragging part, you would have to create all these objects dynamically with javascript.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This gives a clue on what to do.